# Understanding Data for newly hired

Tags: database, data-warehouse

I have just started a new job, where I have to maintain the data warehouse, but the problem is that the company data warehouse gets data from the eautomate, and some other software, and when I look at the tables in the data warehouse, I don't understand anything. What would be the best idea for understanding all the data in the warehouse for analytic purpose? It looks like the eautomate company has build all the tables for the company and no one is here to train me how data got in there. I just felt bad for not being very productive, since its my second week at the job.

Comment: Don't panic.  List all the tables and look at them one at a time.  Write notes and slowly but surely it will start to come together.  Take the time to talk to the users and find out: what they do with the data, what it means to them and what they want from it.  If can you; clone the database and experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, there has to be a contact for eAutomate that set up the DB. Without having experience with eAutomate, you're handicapped.

I'd recommend getting a idea what which DBs/Tables exist, then I'd get permission to add records/modify some test data in eAutomate. Start looking in tables that seem to correspond with area of eAutomate you modified data in.

Your best bet is to get some domain knowledge before you dive into the DB.

Just my .02. Hope it helps!